# How can I use cin.get() to detect an empty user input?

Tags: c++, input

I've written some code to detect empty user input:

```
if(cin.get() == '\n')
{
   cout<<"ENTER WAS PRESSED"<<endl;
}
```

But for some reason if the user presses ENTER it just keeps advancing to the next line as I press ENTER.

Comment: I think you have to use noskipws or something along those lines. By default cin skips whitespace and \n is whitespace IIRC.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the user is supposed to enter a number and I wanted to know what to do in order to make sure that if the user presses ENTER then the warning message pops up

Comment: Keep asking until you get what you want?

Comment: @Borgleader: Whitespace and `/n` are different entites. They are treated differently by the compiler. Also, The ASCII value of whitespace is 32 while that of `\n` is 10.

Comment: @ChosenTorture: The C++ compiler treats `\n` as whitespace for all contexts discussed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code does your job.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string in = "";
    int n = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number: ";
        getline(cin, in);
        std::stringstream s(in);
        if (s >> n)
            break;
        cout << "Invalid number, please try again\n";
     }
     return 0;
}
```

AFAIK, I think that you shouldn't use the `get()` function to input numbers. The `get()` function is designed to input characters and it behaves as an [Unformatted Input Function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedInputFunction). The `>>` operator seems better for this job. The extraction operator `>>` will wait for your input if you press the ENTER key because it will ignore it. However, the newline input is stored in the `cin` input stream. You can also try a combination of the `peek()` and the `seekg()` function to check for an existing newline input in the input stream and do what you want.

Answer (score 8):

In this form your code works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    while (true) {
        if (std::cin.get() == '\n') {
            std::cout<<"ENTER WAS PRESSED"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, your further comments reveal that your code also includes this:

```
    while(!(cin >> number) || (number < 0 || number > 3) || (cin.get() == '\n'))
```

There is your trouble.

What you are trying will not work with that particular `while`, but many first-term students of C++ ask similar questions, so let me explain.  The reason that it will not work is that your concept of `std::cin` is vague.  (By the way, `std::cin`, please, or `cin` preceded by `using std::cin;` if you must.  The textbook that is telling you to issue `using namespace std;` should be burned.)

The object `std::cin` is a *stream*—from your perspective, a queue from which your program can accept available input characters when it wishes to do so.  Important:  `std::cin` is not a command or an operation, but an object called a stream.  By analogy with speech, you may be thinking of `std::cin` as a verb, only it isn't:  it is a noun.  By itself, `std::cin` does not do anything.

What does do something is the extraction operator `>>`.  What also does something is the single-character fetching member function `.get()`.  Both of these retrieve previously unseen characters from the stream `std::cin`.  So, the `>>` retrieves some characters which the program puts into `number`, then tests.  Then the `.get()` retrieves *another,* previously unseen character, which the program checks to see whether it is a newline.  But why does your program treat the former group of characters as a possible number and the latter, single character as a possible newline?  How does it know that the former group of characters does not begin with a newline?

My suggestion is to try some simpler test programs for a while, using either `>>` or `.get()`, but not both in the same program.  For now, using both at once is understandably confusing you.  Stream input can be tricky.  You are unlikely to benefit from further explanation until you get this point straight in your mind, and that will probably take you an hour of trial and experiment.  Good luck.

Comment: I have mine in a while loop

Comment: while(!(cin >> number) || (number < 0 || number > 3)  || (cin.get() == '\n'))

Comment: Also newb here: Why shouldn't you use "using namespace std;"?

Comment: @Bobby: Because "using namespace std;" dumps the standard namespace. It disables the namespace mechanism of C++ with respect to standard library symbols. Suppose for example that you have defined a function `bar()`. Suppose that you inadvertently refer to it later as `baz()`. No problem, right? The compiler will flag this for you. However, suppose that the standard library offers a `std::baz()`. What happens after "using namespace std;"? Better is "using std::baz;" which, instead of dumping hundreds of standard library symbols the programmer does not know, imports only the one desired symbol.

Comment: @Bobby: C++ was a commercial success before being adopted as an instructional language. Unfortunately, in the U.S. academic market, one of the first widely used textbooks (I will spare it the embarrassment of naming it here), which is still fairly widely used, was opportunistically introduced into the then void of available collegiate C++ textbooks *by an author who did not really know C++*. That author had the student dump the namespace. Dumping the namespace is an anti-idiomatic hack in C++. I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Makes sense.